# calling outlook redemption 64 bit from

Tags: outlook-redemption

We have an application(built on release x86) and outlook vsto ribbon(built on release x86) and we are using Outlook redemption to communicate in between.

Redemption.RDOSession RDOObj = (Redemption.RDOSession)Activator.CreateInstance(objsession_late);

everything is working fine for 32 bit outlook. Now we have to extend our outlook vsto ribbon for 64 bit outlook so vsto compiled with release x64 and using 64 bit outlook redemption dll. here comes my issue we cant build my application on x64 as we have many 32 bit dll references. now we are trying to call outlook redemption 64 bit from our 32 bit application and getting System.BadImageFormatException(which is obvious). is there a way to resolve this please advise.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is to be expected - a 32 bit process cannot load a 64 bit dll (see http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/faq.htm#ErrorCreatingRedemptionObject).

The only workaround is to move your MAPI/Redemption specific code into a separate exe and compile it in both x86 and x64. Then your main app can launch the appropriate version of that auxiliary exe based on the Outlook bitness.

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your reply is there any sample code or code snippet or some article on this if so please share.

Comment: Which part are you having problems with?